# jQuery UI Slider Handle Not Showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Here is the widget I am building: http://widgets.pegwise.com/720x90/

There are no javascript or css errors, and the background image I have for the handle is valid. Why is it not showing on the slider in the lower right corner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CSS position:relative to  and position:absolute to div#slider a.ui-slider-handle (just tested with FireBug).

Comment: can you give more details please, im facing the same issue, and I dont understand your message fully. Thanks.